# Exchange of a sequence of likelihood ratios and an upper bound inside expectation

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

Consider two probability measures $P$ and $P_0$ having the same support $X \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and densities  $p$ and $p_0$ with respect to the Lebesgue density. Let $X_1, \ldots,X_n$ be iid according to $P_0$ and define the likelihood ratio $\Lambda_n:=\prod_{i=1}^np(X_i)/p_0(X_i)$. The sequence $(\Lambda_n)$ is uniformly tight (e.g. van der Vaart, Asymptotic statistics, 2000, page 88). Moreover, under various conditions involving distances or divergences between $p$ and $p_0$, it can be shown that $\Lambda_n \leq e^{nc}$ eventually $P_0^{(\infty)}$ almost surely, for a positive constant $c$.

Can we then conclude that, for large enough $n$, $\mathbb{E}\Lambda_n \epsilon_{B_n} \leq e^{nc} P_0^{(n)}(B_n)$, for any sequence of measurable sets $B_n$, where $\epsilon_{B_n}$ is the indicator function of the set $B_n$ at $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$?

Comment: I can't make sense of "$\Lambda_n \leq e^{nc}$ eventually $P_0^{(\infty)}$ almost surely". Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, Q)$ denote the ground probability space. Do you simply mean $Q(\liminf_n \Lambda_n \leq e^{nc}) =1$ ?

Comment: I mean $Q(\liminf_{n \to \infty}\{\omega : \Lambda_n(\omega)/e^{nc}\leq1 \})=1$.

Comment: Ok, I meant that too. Do you have a reference for this result ?

Comment: E.g. if you take $P$ in an $\epsilon$ Kullback-Leibler ball centered at $P_0$, then by the central limit theorem $n^{-1}\log \Lambda_n$ converges almost surely to a value smaller than $\varepsilon$. If you let $\varepsilon <c$, the almost sure upper bound for $\Lambda_n$ then follows.